# CDI: Discovering beans from multiple ClassLoaders

Tags: java, classloader, cdi

I'm facing a problem with my CDI extension. Im using the beforeBeanDiscovery method to add multiple classes to the CDI bean discovery:

```
public void beforeBeanDiscovery(@Observes BeforeBeanDiscovery bbd, BeanManager beanManager) {
  Class clazz = MyClassLoader.loadClass("com.my.example.clazz");
  final AnnotatedType<?> annotatedType = beanManager.createAnnotatedType(clazz);
  bbd.addAnnotatedType(annotatedType, annotatedType.toString());
}
```

This is working fine and all my beans are discovered. The problem occurs when I'm loading my classes from multiple ClassLoaders. Every time the ClassLoader changes the added classes from the previous ClassLoader get lost.

This is how I load my classes from multiple ClassLoaders:

```
  for (MyClassLoader cl : classLoaders) {
    for (Class<?> clazz : cl.getClasses()) {
      final AnnotatedType<?> annotatedType = beanManager.createAnnotatedType(clazz);
      bbd.addAnnotatedType(annotatedType, annotatedType.toString());
    }
  }
```

Can anyone please explain to me why this happens and how I can avoid this behavior?

Thanks in advance.
Best regards,
Gerry

Comment: I'm curious, how are you starting CDI?

Comment: CDI is started by my application server. I don't start it manually if you mean that.

Comment: Ok... I think you need to explain what you're trying to do a bit more.  Typically you don't mess with class loaders when inside an app server.

Comment: I'm not messing with class loaders. During application startup some external jar files are loaded and each jar gets its own class loader for security reasons. Now I'm trying to get these "external jar-file classes" discovered by CDI but the above problem occurs.

Comment: These are JARs outside your classpath?

Comment: External means outside of classpath, of course. Please don't suggest to change this or ask why it is like that because thats simply something I can't change.

Comment: Ok, so ultimately what you're seeing is expected behaviour as long as you're using distinct class loaders in an app server (which an app should never do).  CDI BeanManagers are tied to class loaders.